# How to define django templates folders?

Tags: django

I want to build my project with regards to html templates like this:

```
├───app1
│   ├───...
│   └───...
├───app2
│   ├───...
│   └───...
├───project
│   ├───...
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───navbar.html
│   │   └───footer.html
│   │   └───sidebar.html
│   │   └───conbined.html
│   │   └───content_app1.html
│   │   └───content_app2.html
```

The reason is that I want to devide my site into several parts as shows below. Thus in every app folder there are no html files. The `navbar, footer and sidebar` are always shown, while the `content_appN.html` can be activated accordingly. The `conbined.html` conbines them all.

[image]

My try (in `settings.py`):

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

In `app1`: `views.py`:

```
def app1_content(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/combined.html')
```

Actually I have tried almost every methods I could find online, but still dont know how to do it. Please dont laugh me for this idea to build the website like this. Could anyone please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding the problem statement you have is you want to keep your templates directory inside a particular folder and according to me your manage.py file is placed at the same level as your project folder so i am explaining you the solution as per that only. so to define django templates folders what you need to do is inside your settings.py you need to set it like this :-

```
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project','templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So, Here's the explaination What i did is set the TEMPLATES_DIR variable with reference to base directory that will take the path to folder where manage.py of your django project is being kept now i am concatinating the projects and templates directory just to navigate the exact folder structure that you kept for your templates in your project.

I hope you found this helpful. if you have any more doubts i'll be happy to answer those also.

Happy Coding. :-)